# RN react-native opens editor while running

Tags: react-native

For some unknown reason, the `react-native start` command, while running for a while, opens an editor with the following message:

> Opening ../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactChildReconciler.js with vim

Not an issue (it still works), but more of an annoyance and I was wondering why it was doing this and that maybe it's a features I'm missing out, like stack traces after an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor opens when you click a line in the stack trace on the "red screen". Pretty easy to unknowingly do if you're running an emulator and are using the mouse to bring focus to it. It appears this is intended behavior (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6103)

You can work around it by using a launch line like `EDITOR=true react-native start`, while it will still "open an editor" that instantly exits, it wont break your shell.